# Why is curl given by a cross product?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, curl, divergence-theorem

I've googled a lot but in most places, they usually only show how to compute it which I by now can do. But I wanna understand why the cross product between nabla and the vector give us the curl. So far I've managed to understand that when we are talking about the curl we are interested in the vector that points upwards or downwards (perpendicular) to the actual curl (rotation) like the green vector down here:

[image]

And then since the cross product between two vectors give us another vector orthogonal to both I finally understood why we do $\nabla\times \vec{F}$. Am I correct so far? Otherwise feel free to correct me (I actually want you to). But then my first question is why does this "green" vector in the picture define the curl? For example in Stoke's theorem we use curl to calculate higher dimension of "Green", but in Green's theorem we don't take any perpendicular vectors (obviously because z is non existent). This brings me to my second question which is how is the curl related to Green's thorem? Until now I had assumed that the green's theorem was just like line integral where we are only interested in the the field vector's component's that are parallel to the curve's tangents.

But in general I am confused and I'd really appreciate it if someone could just clear these things up for me?

Comment: I like the question but I will be (pleasantly) surprised if there's a short and elementary answer. Part of the issue is making really precise what the curl *should be* if the vector field isn't just rotating around a point. Of course if you restrict the vector fields to ones of that form then it should be a direct computation to check that the cross product with nabla gives the correct quantity.

Comment: "And then since the cross product between two vectors give us another vector orthogonal to both I finally understood why we do $\nabla\times\vec F$. Am I correct so far?" I don't understand how anything you've written is related to the divergence. As for curl, it's not clear to me what sort of answer you want. Are you specifically asking about Green's theorem? About why we use normal vectors to represent planes? Or are you looking for a sort of "geometric" definition of curl instead of the usual coordinate definition $\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jF_k$?

Comment: If we consider "curl" to be the *correct differential operation* that we must apply to a vector field to ensure that Stokes' theorem holds in three-dimensions and Green's theorem holds in two-dimensions then most of the mystery goes away.
Both these theorems say that work done by the vector field around a closed loop is equal to the integral of "curl" over the enclosed region. Pondering why in 3D that curl is a cross product is nearly pointless. What counts is that it relates both sides of Stokes' theorem correctly. ...

Comment: I find the integral version better suited for geometric interpretation than cross product in 3D vs $\partial_xF_y-\partial_yF_x$ in 2D.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I totally meant the cross $\vec{F} \times \nabla$. I accidentally wrote the dot product sign because I was working with both but this question is just about cross product. What I wanna understand is what defines the curl? I want more than just "the cross product" but I wanna know what the cross product is giving us the curl? Why are we taking the cross product and not for example division? Because right now you can tell me nabla divided by the vector field gives the curl I'd believe you because I have no idea what defines the curl mathematically?

Comment: When I was trying to figure that out I watched a Khan Academy video where he said the curls is given by the normal vector to it and that green theorem is a 2D curl etc and my whole perception of greens theorem changed? So now I also wanna understand how the green theorem is related to curl?

Comment: @KurtG. "Pondering why in 3D that curl is a cross product is nearly pointless." I couldn't disagree more. What a strange attitude to have. The curl involves the cross product exactly because the cross product of two vectors represents the plane they span; rotations happen within a plane. $\nabla\times F$ is essentially the average of how $F$ varies over all planes containing it.

Answer (score 1):

For vector fields $V,W$ and a function $f$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \nabla\times (fV)&=(\nabla f)\times V+f(\nabla\times V)\\
    \nabla\times (V+W)&=\nabla\times V + \nabla\times W
\end{align*}

If one also knows that the constant coordinate vector fields $e_1,e_2,e_3$ have zero curl, one can derive the curl formula as follows.

For any vector field $V$, there are functions $a,b,c$ such that $V=ae_1+be_2+ce_3$. Then

\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
    \nabla \times V&=\nabla \times (ae_1)+\nabla \times (be_2)+\nabla \times (ce_3)\\
    &=(\nabla a)\times e_1+\cancel{a(\nabla\times e_1)}+(\nabla b)\times e_2+\cancel{b(\nabla\times e_2)}+(\nabla c)\times e_3+\cancel{c(\nabla\times e_3)}\\
    &=(\nabla a)\times e_1+(\nabla b)\times e_2+(\nabla c)\times e_3
\end{align*}

And this last expression is formally equivalent to the rule of taking the cross product of the vector field with the "vector" $\nabla=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z})^t$.